# Missing apache2 on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.10

I want to install Apache on Ubuntu 10.10.

I've tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

Any ideas where I can find the apache2 package?

Comment: You are missing some repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Also do an `apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post!  It'll show you step by step [LAMP Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-distributions/4-ubuntu/1239-install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat)

It starts with works very well for my Ubuntu Box:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Comment: Instead of going through the tasksel interface you can just `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

Answer (score 1):

The apache2 metapackage is available from security.ubuntu.com, make sure you have the following entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
>   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
>   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
>   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
>   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
>   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse

Also, keep in mind that apt-get does not automatically download the repository contents every time you run it (unlike yum). You have to do that manually with `sudo apt-get update`.